# static keyword inside array [] brackets

Tags: c, arrays, function, static

I recently came across new use of `static` keyword.
What does `static`  mean here?

```
void fun(int some_array[static 7]);
```

**EDIT** : can someone give an example where this can be useful?

Comment: taken from http://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2013-02-18-static-array-indices.html ?

Answer (score 15):

The standard says in 6.7.6.3:

> A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to
>   ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’, where the type qualifiers (if any) are
>   those specified within the [ and ] of the array type derivation. If
>   **the keyword static also appears within the [ and ] of the array type
>   derivation**, then for each call to the function, the value of the
>   corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first
>   element of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the
>   size expression.

It's a feature introduced in C99. So there you have it: `some_array` must be at least 7 elements long.

---

As they say, there can't be a new standard without a new usage for the keyword `static`.

Comment: "As they say, there can't be a new standard without a new usage for the keyword `static`", I know that feel bro.